# Unable to disable SSLv3 in Apache 2.4.18

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, openssl

One of my client wanted me to upgrade openssl and Apache on his server because he want to receive an A from SSLLabs. I went ahead and upgraded to Apache 2.4.18 and openssl to version 1.0.2e. I then modified Apache's SSL configuration to match the following:

```
# SSL Protocols/Ciphers
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256::kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK
SSLCompression off
```

I ran an SSL Test from SSL Labs and I still receive the following warning:

> This server is vulnerable to the POODLE attack. If possible, disable SSL 3 to mitigate. Grade capped to C.

In the protocols list, it says YES to SSL 3 even if the above statement says it should be disabled.

I've tried many ciphers combinisations by searching on the web and I always gets the same result. I've also searched in any *.conf file for an SSL configuration but there's none except my SSL file above.

The website's URL: https://orders.expotools.biz

SSL Labs: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=orders.expotools.biz

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to disable SSLv3 in Apache 2.4.18
>   ...
>   `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3`

Try:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
```

Also see [Apache Module mod_ssl | SSLProtocol](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol) in the handbook.

Comment: Not OP, but this did not work for me