# Test shows SSLv3 enabled even though I've disabled it with SSLProtocol

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

I'm working on remediation for some penetration testing we had done.

The penetration test reports a POODLE vulnerability due to SSv3 being enabled.

However, in the VirtualHost definition of my httpd.conf, I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAdmin mbobak@nitssolutions.com
     ServerName myhost.com
     SSLEngine On
     SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
     SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/e98c5d5c622256c1.crt"
     SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/myhost.key"
     SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/httpd/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt"
     RedirectMatch ^(.*)$ https://myhost.com/ords/f?p=1000:15
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
     RewriteRule .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

Clearly, I have -SSLv3 in the SSLProtocol line above, and everything I've read says that if I disable SSLv3, I won't be subject to the POODLE attack.

But I've tried Qualys online SSL tester, and an 'ssl-poodle' nmap script, both of which tell me I'm still vulnerable.

Help?

Can anyone explain what I've missed here?

Thanks!

Update:
This is on Oracle Linux 7.3, with Apache/2.4.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to disable SSLv3 in Apache 2.4.18](https://superuser.com/questions/1029529/unable-to-disable-sslv3-in-apache-2-4-18)

Comment: Worth pointing out that `TLSv1` is not considered secure either.  You really should only have `TLSv1.2+` enabled in 2018.  Anyways update your question, to include what version of OpenSSL you are using, that is considered to be important information in a case like this.

Comment: [How to force all Apache connections to use TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2](https://superuser.com/questions/829793/how-to-force-all-apache-connections-to-use-tlsv1-1-or-tlsv1-2/829801#829801)

Comment: Your problem is likely the lack of the `SSLCipherSuite` and the fact Qualys doesn't have any valid vTLSv1.1 only tests, which likely means your problem is your version of OpenSSL doesn't include TLSv1.2 by default.  I would submit an answer to your specific question, but an existing [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/829793/how-to-force-all-apache-connections-to-use-tlsv1-1-or-tlsv1-2/829801#829801), already explains the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: You could of course just cheat and using a more [secure](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=apache-2.4.18&openssl=1.1.0&hsts=yes&profile=modern) configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  Although I had the correct `SSLProtocol` statement in every `VirtualHost` definition in my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file, it's apparently required in the default `VirtualHost` definition in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`.

Once I added it to ssl.conf, it started working.